# Arduino binary LED 10 bit display

Tags: arduino-uno, adc

I'm working on a simple ADC project, the goal is to adjust the on/off of the LEDs according to the binary reading (1-on,0-off). I've tried this with 8 bit, and it works as intended. But on 10 bit, two of the LEDs with representation of 2^8 and 2^9 won't turn on even though the reading on the serial monitor is 1023 (should be 1111111111 -all LEDs on). I wonder if there's anything wrong with my code or circuit?
(I'm totally new to arduino, sorry for the noobness)
-I'm using Arduino UNO R3, the details are shown in the image[image]

```
void setup(){
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.print("Decimal=");
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print("\tBinary=");
  Serial.println(sensorValue,BIN);
  
  if(sensorValue>=0&&sensorValue<=1023){
    digitalWrite(4,(sensorValue&1));
    digitalWrite(5,(sensorValue&2));
    digitalWrite(6,(sensorValue&4));
    digitalWrite(7,(sensorValue&8));
    digitalWrite(8,(sensorValue&16));
    digitalWrite(9,(sensorValue&32));
    digitalWrite(10,(sensorValue&64));
    digitalWrite(11,(sensorValue&128));
    digitalWrite(12,(sensorValue&256));
    digitalWrite(13,(sensorValue&512));
  }
  delay(20); 
}
```

Comment: write a debug sketch ... turn on all of the LEDs ... does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/), the second parameter of
`digitalWrite()` should be either `HIGH` or `LOW`. Thus, in order to be
compliant with the published API, you are supposed to write:

```cpp
digitalWrite(12, sensorValue&256 ? HIGH : LOW);
```

In practice, `digitalWrite()` interprets any non-zero value as `HIGH`.
However, [its prototype](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.3/cores/arduino/Arduino.h#L135) is:

```cpp
void digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t val);
```

Both parameters have the type `uint8_t`, which means “8-bit unsigned
integer”. If you provide a value that doesn't fit in 8 bits, the
implicit cast to `uint8_t` will reduce it modulo 2<sup>8</sup>. Thus,
both 256 and 512 become zero through the implicit cast.

Comment: Your trinary operator trick would fix the 8 bit truncation problem AND send the documented values to the function. Personally, I'd write a function that took bit index and a value and returned HIGH or LOW, and call that. D.R.Y.

Comment: I know OP is new, but fancy not writing to ports for ganged output.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, digitalWrite does not take any `int` != 0 as HIGH

Rather consider supplying a boolean (one byte value)

```
   digitalWrite(12,(sensorValue&256)==256);
   digitalWrite(12,(sensorValue>>8)&1);
```

or similar